# Some links on table not working

Tags: html, css

Four links on the third column 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and fourth row (Order Form PDF, Rental App PDF, Married Rental PDF, and Consent Form PDF) are not linking for some reason.

Below is the code:

```css
#applicationtable {
  width:550px;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-bottom:50px;
  margin-top:50px;
}

#applicationtable table td  {
  text-align: :left;
  padding:10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  font-size:.9em;
}

#applicationtable table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left:8px;
}


#applicationtable a:link {
  color:hsla(243, 100%, 50%, 1);
}

#applicationtable a:visited {
  color:hsla(243, 100%, 70%, 1);
}

#applicationtable a:hover {
  color:hsla(243, 100%, 50%, .25);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div  class="floatleft">
    <div id="applicationtable">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><strong>Landlord Rental Applications</strong></th>
            <th scope="col">Word Document</th>
            <th scope="col">PDF Document</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Order Form</td>
            <td><a href="../documents/orderform.doc">Order Form Word</a></td>
            <td><a href="../documents/orderform.pdf">Order Form  PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tablebackground">Rental Application</td>
            <td class="tablebackground"><a href="../documents/rentalapp.doc">Rental App Word</a></td>
            <td class="tablebackground"><a href="../documents/rentalapp.pdf">Rental App PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Married Rental Application</td>
            <td><a href="../documents/rentalmar.doc">Married Rental Word</a></td>
            <td><a href="../documents/rentalmar.pdf">Married Rental PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tablebackground">Applicant Consent Form</td>
            <td class="tablebackground"><a href="../documents/consentform.doc">Consent Form Word</a></td>
            <td class="tablebackground"><a href="../documents/consentform.pdf">Consent Form PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lease Agrement</td>
            <td><a href="../documents/lease.doc">Lease Word</a></td>
            <td><a href="../documents/lease.pdf">Lease Rental PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tablebackground">Property Management Agrement</td>
            <td class="tablebackground"><a href="../documents/propagreement.doc">Prop Agreement Word</a></td>
            <td class="tablebackground"><a href="../documents/propagreement.pdf">Prop Agreement PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Denial Letter</td>
            <td><a href="../documents/denialletter.doc">Applicant Denial Word</a></td>
            <td><a href="../documents/denialletter.pdf">Applicant Denial PDF</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="smalltext">Everything needed to process a report is in the order form download!</td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here they are working as expected, but the document does not exist (error 404).

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you

Comment: Nothing here should stop these links to be clickable. I suspect a non-visible element to stand hover your table. Can we have a link to the full version? (or try to inspect the table by yourself to see if "something" is over it)

Comment: In what way are they 'not linking'? Could it be that the files are not where you think they are?

Answer (score 0):

The code and links appear to work properly; however, you should check to make sure the PDF files referenced in the anchor tags actually exist on your server...that is likely the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

OK I had another div blocking that one.  The other div was a relative div to get it over the header.  So I just put position:relative; in the css and that took care of it.  Sorry for wasting anyone's time!

Thanks,

Brandon C Varn